# How to write javascript code for income tax calculator according to gender?

Tags: javascript, html

If salary is 50000 then it will print tax is not applicable.
If amount between 50001 to 150000 then for male it will be 10% and for female it'll be 7%
If greater than 150000 it will be 15% for men and 10% for female

I'm stuck in this....

function calculateTax(){

            let sal = document.getElementById("salary").value;

            let m = document.getElementById("male").Checked;

            let f = document.getElementById("female").Checked;

            

            

            if (sal

Comment: What is the problem? Where did you get stuck? Your requirements are already almost written in pseudo-code, so all you have to do is "translating" them in actual code.

Comment: I'm posting my code snippet

Comment: I think a big chunk of your snippet is missing; you posted two lines of JavaScript code that is clearly incomplete and refers to some HTML elements you are not sharing

Comment: Can u show condition segment for this

Comment: document.getElementById("male").checked not .Checked. Use camelCase in Javascript codes, avoid PascalCase & Capitalize. I have extended your codes below. Please check whether it has cleared where you have stuck or not. Thanks

Comment: Can _you_ show a genuine attempt to solve this by yourself, before asking to receive a ready-made solution?

Comment: Yes .. i got the solutions.... There was mistake on checked .. thank you Titan XP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style>

        *{

            text-align: center;

            padding: 12px;

            font-size: 25px;

        }

    </style>

</head>

<script>

    function calculateTax(){

        let sal = document.getElementById("salary").value;

        let m = document.getElementById("male").Checked;

        let f = document.getElementById("female").Checked;

        

        

        if (sal<=50000) {

            document.write("Amount is not need to pay tax.");

        }

        else if(sal<=150000 && m === male) {

            let result = sal*0.01;

            ans.innerHTML = result;

        }

        else if(sal<=150000 && f === female) {

            let result = sal*0.07;

            ans.innerHTML = result;

        }

    }

</script>

<body>

    <label for="">Gross salary : </label>

    <input type="number" name="" id="salary"><br>

    <label for="">Gender :</label>

    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male">Male

    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female">Female<br>

    <input type="button" value="Calculate Tax" id="tax" onclick="calculateTax()">

    <p id="ans"></p>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to complete this task is if construction.
For example:

```
    const salary = 50000;
    const gender = "M";
    
    let tax = 0;
    
    if(salary <= 50000) {
     console.log("tax is not applicable")
    } else if(salary > 50000 && salary <= 150000) {
     if(gender == "M") {
      tax = 10;
     } else {
      tax = 7;
     }
    } else {
     if(gender == "M") {
      tax = 15;
     } else {
      tax = 10;
     }
    }
```

You can also do it in many different ways. In class where implement gender and salary to constructor for exmaple:

```
class TaxCalculator {
 ...code inside.
}
```

Hope it help at start.

Comment: Please do not answer questions that do not show any effort from the OP side; this encourages the abuse of StackOverflow and is not in line with the community guidelines.

Comment: Ok, Understood.

Answer (score 0):

Use statement & Ternary Operator.

HTML

```
  <label>Salary : </label><input type="number" id="salary">
  <input type="checkbox" id="male"><label> Male</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="female"><label> Female</label>
  <button onclick="calculateTax()">Calculate</button>

  <p>Tax Result : <span id="result"></span></p>
```

JS (.checked is lowercase not capitalized)

```
  function calculateTax() {
    let salary = document.getElementById("salary").value;
    let male = document.getElementById("male").checked;
    let female = document.getElementById("female").checked;
    if (male === true && female === true || male === false && female === false) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Please choose either male or female";
    } else if (salary <= 50000) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Tax is not applicable";
    } else if (salary > 50000 && salary <= 150000) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = male === true ? salary * 0.1 : salary * 0.07;
    } else if (salary > 150000) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = male === true ? salary * 0.15 : salary * 0.1;
    };
  };
```